# $x+y=\pm \arccos(z)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

when we have such equation:
$$\cos(x+y)=z$$
can we say that
$$ z= \arccos(x+y)
$$
or
$$z = \pm \arccos(x+y)
$$
that's what my professor said, we should care that it might be negative. I got lost. Because i know that if the angle $x+y$ between $\pi/2$ and $-\pi/2$ so the cosine will give a negative answer. so I am not sure why we need to insert the $\pm$ in the equation of $z$, and at what conditions this work?

Comment: See here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions

Comment: I don't see why we need $x+y$ in this question, what is that doing which cannot be done by just $x$?